# how to check not Digit Only android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to show an error if inputs in edit Text are any thing except numbers. I tried this code but it seems incorrect and does not work.

```
if(!EditText.text.isDigitsOnly()){
      EditText.error = "myError"
   }
```

I know about `android:inputType="number"` but I should not use it.
I can use a loop to check it myself but I need a much cleaner way.

Comment: You can always use Integer/Long/Float/Double parsing and if it throws an exception the format is wrong

Comment: "does not work" - how so?  Do you mean that you're using the `EditText` *class* rather than a particular instance of that class?

Comment: by EditText I mean one of the views in xml not a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created some functions hope it helps you

```
fun String?.hasOnlyDigits() : Boolean = try {
if (this.isNullOrEmpty())
    false
else Pattern.matches("[0-9]+", this)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    false
}

fun String.isInt() : Boolean = try {
this.toIntOrNull() != null
} catch (e: Exception) {
   e.printStackTrace()
   false
}

    fun String.isDouble() : Boolean = try {
    this.toDoubleOrNull() != null
} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    false
}
```

and you can use it as following

```
    if(!editText.text?.toString().hasOnlyDigits()){
       editText.error = "myError"
    }
```

Comment: why do you need all of this code if you can just use `toIntOrNull`

Comment: you don't need all this code, I'm just creating examples for different use cases,
Imagine that he wants to validate his string as national id, so using isInt is not valid and should use hasOnlyDigits, and if he is validating for the price he can use isDouble, he didn't describe the problem in detail and he just said he can't specify input type for Edittext, so I assumed multiple use cases.

Comment: There’s no point in using try/catch for the “…OrNull()” functions. They never throw. That’s the whole point of them.

Comment: It is so kind of you. you're right; it's for validating national id and I should mention that. I'll use the first method. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex:

```
if ("[0-9]+".toRegex().matches(YOUR_STRING)) {
    // Only digits
}
```

Change **YOUR_STRING** to the string you wish to check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex pattern and match,

```
val regexStr = "^[0-9]*$";

if(yourid.text.toString().trim().matches(regexStr))
{
    //contains only numbers
}
else{
    //contains other types too
}
```

This will be helpful when you are trying to validate only numbers.